XGBoost and LGBM models size depends on training data size for a given set of params whereas Catboost doesnt
I am comparing models in a walk forward cross validation setup, under python 3.11. For a given set of hyperparameters, xgboost and LGBM models size (when pickled or saved using the library saving methods) monotonically increases with the train size, while it stays constant for CatBoost as I would expect as there is the same number of trees, max_depth and all.
Do you have any idea if xgboost/lgbm models save anything that could be removed for inference, like gradients for example? What am I missing?

It is the number of splits that count.

Yes, that’s clear. My question concerns a given configuration of hyper parameters which implies a bound on the number of splits possibles.
